# Criteria for saving best model during training neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, model-selection, conv-neural-network, loss-functions

I am doing 4-class semantic segmentation with U-net using generalised dice loss as loss function.

General approach to save best model during training is to monitor validation loss at each epoch and save the model if val loss decreases than previous minimum.

But, I am interested in the "model which gives best the average dice score of 4 classes".

During training in my case, using validation loss as criteria doesn't lead to best avg dice score. So what should I consider the best model the one with less validation loss or highest validation dice score?

Below is my validation loss and avg dice score after each epoch. Out of this which epoch gives the best model?

```
epoch  1/10     validation loss: 0.95     avg dice score: 0.17
epoch  2/10     validation loss: 0.86     avg dice score: 0.23
epoch  3/10     validation loss: 0.77     avg dice score: 0.34
epoch  4/10     validation loss: 0.74     avg dice score: 0.40
epoch  5/10     validation loss: 0.71     avg dice score: 0.45
epoch  6/10     validation loss: 0.69     avg dice score: 0.34
epoch  7/10     validation loss: 0.79     avg dice score: 0.45
epoch  8/10     validation loss: 0.75     avg dice score: 0.51
epoch  9/10     validation loss: 0.76     avg dice score: 0.36
epoch 10/10     validation loss: 0.75     avg dice score: 0.38
```

If I go by val loss as criteria epoch-6 gives the best model, if i choose avg dice score as critieria epoch-8 gives the best model? how to choose?

Comment: Why not just measure the average DICE score on the validation set?

Comment: Actually average DICE score is measured on the validation set itself

Comment: Then what's the problem here?

Comment: My question is, what should be the criteria to choose the best model? with min validation loss or highest dice score?

Comment: Is your criteria for "best" the validation loss or the DICE score?

Comment: criteria is DICE score, but that doesn't corresponds mininum val loss

Comment: If DICE is the sole criterion for the best model, why does it matter if it corresponds to the minimum val loss or not?